# Decode request ID in Google Cloud Storage logs

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, httprequest, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Storage logs include a field `s_request_id`, which is described as "The request identifier" in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs).  It looks to be base64url encoded, and is of a variable length in the range of 90-130 characters (in the logs that I have).

This seems to be too long and irregular to be a simple ID, so I hope that it's somehow an encoding of the HTTP request that triggered the log.

How is the `r_request_id` field generated, and what (if any) information can be extracted from it?

---

To help, here is some example data:

s_request_id: `AEnB2UpjhBkYMympt9UW0R3yQ0Bqk5-jXzHdiJ-WVKJp7AYfSupObC5pvInXWQptATRMqUon4EcJmFnaRtT77EYH_Za7zLiooPQp6fDKhBATiOTrxqSB4y0`

time_micros: `1520197206174280`